# Vue data() is unavailable in events when using @microsoft/fetch-event-source for Server Sent Events

Tags: javascript, vue.js, server-sent-events

I'm trying to use `fetchEventSource` (from `@microsoft/fetch-event-source`) to process Server Sent Events for streaming data to the client. It works, in that the data is returned and I can log it to the console, but when I try to update my vue data in the `onmessage` event, I get the error:

`TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'messages')`

Any thoughts on the best way to get this working?

Basic test template:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>
      <label>Message</label><br />
      <textarea id="messages" v-model="messages"></textarea><br />
      <button @click="getMessage">GET</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
```

and the script:

```
import { fetchEventSource } from "@microsoft/fetch-event-source";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      messages: "",
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.messages = "initialized"; // this works
  },
  methods: {
    getMessage() {
      fetchEventSource("url-here", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        onmessage(msg) {
          console.log("message", msg.data); // this works - data is here!
          this.messages = msg.data; // this returns the error
        },
      });
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with arrow function or like :

```
getMessage() {
  const self = this
  fetchEventSource("url-here", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    onmessage(msg) {
      console.log("message", msg.data); // this works - data is here!
      self.messages = msg.data; // this returns the error
    },
  });
},
```

Comment: Thank you! This works and it makes sense to me. I'm still learning! I need to look into arrow functions too because I feel like that is an important piece that I'm missing.

Comment: @obliojoe You are welcome mate, take a look here [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) , cheers :)